# Using LAG to create an ID activity timeline

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, lag

Here's the base query:

```
SELECT
id,
date,
result
FROM
table
ORDER BY 1,2
```

I have a results set that looks like this:

```
+-----+----------+--------+
| id  |   date   | result |
+-----+----------+--------+
| 123 | 2/21/19  |      1 |
| 123 | 7/19/19  |      4 |
| 123 | 8/17/19  |      1 |
| 456 | 3/4/19   |      1 |
| 456 | 8/15/19  |      5 |
+-----+----------+--------+
```

I'm trying to basically build a timeline for each IDs activity change. So the ideal output would look like this:

```
+-----+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| id  | date_1  | result_1 | date_2  | result_2 | date_3  | result_3 |
+-----+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
| 123 | 2/21/19 |        1 | 7/19/19 |        4 | 8/17/19 |        1 |
| 456 | 3/4/19  |        1 | 8/15/19 |        5 |         |          |
+-----+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+
```

I know this would involve using the Lag function (I think?) I'm still fairly new to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` or conditional aggregation.  I might go for the latter:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as date_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then result end) as result_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as date_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then result end) as result_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then date end) as date_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then result end) as result_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```